# Inserting a Swing BoxLayout graphically via Netbeans palette

Tags: swing, netbeans, layout-manager, boxlayout, palette

I'm trying to insert a Swing **BoxLayout** to my jFrame graphically using netbeans palette, but i can't find any way to do it

[Here is my my NB palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJqNx.png)

any suggestion or help will be welcomed :)

---

Edit:

Problem resolved thanks to @kyal-bond 's solution : just i have to put a Panel, then right click on it and choose "Set layout" then choosing "Box Layout".

Thank you again @kyal-bond ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add Layouts to JFrames, first add a Panel to that frame and then you may add layouts to that. JFrames are kind of just window containers and don't actually do much in terms of editing layouts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer my friend

Comment: You are totally right, but the problem is that even when i'm working in a Panel, the BoxLayout doesn't show in my palette :(

Comment: In your inspector/navigator pane have you tried right clicking on your panel and selecting setlayout?

Comment: Thank you so much my friend !! This trick resolved my problem ^_^

Comment: Unfortunately i tried to upvote it but it keeps saying that it will not show because i'm having less than 15 reputations. i'm sure that our friends will upvote it soon my bro ^^